# What is the most efficient method to set the states of two dependent parameters with React hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I need to set the state of baseValue when the input field is changed:

```
<input type="number" value={baseValue} min="1" onChange={handleBaseVal}/>
```

and then display the targetValue which equals baseVal * exchangeRate.
Plus, targetValue can change from:

```
<input type="number" value={targetValue} onChange={handleTargetVal}/>
```

and if the targetValue changes, the baseValue should change to targetVal / exchangeRate.

This is my approch:

```
const [baseVal, setBaseVal] = useState(1);
const [targetVal, setTargetVal] = useState();
```

and

```
const handleBaseVal = (e) => {
 setBaseVal(() => 
  { 
   const newBaseVal = e.target.value;
   setTargetVal(newBaseVal * exchangeRate);
   return newBaseVal;
  });   
 }


const handleTargetVal = (e) => {
 setTargetVal(() => {
   const newTargetVal = e.target.value;
   setBaseVal(newTargetVal / exchangeRate);
   return newTargetVal;
 });
 }
```

This gives me the desired result but my question is whether this a correct approach and more importantly, are there any better ways?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a hook for both of those. `targetVal` is derived from `baseVal`, so the component only needs to re-render when `baseVal` is changed.

You should simply define a function like this outside of your component:

```
const calculateTargetVal = (base) => base * exchangeRate;
```

Then within your component:

```
const targetVal = calculateTargetVal(baseVal);
```

And then use `targetVal` as you would use the value from the hook.

---

EDIT: A more complete answer to keep track of both variables in parallel.

Define two functions outside of your component, something like:

```
const toTargetVal = (value) => value * exchangeRate;
const fromTargetVal = (value) => value / exchangeRate;
```

Then within your component:

```
const [baseVal, setBaseVal] = useState(1);
const targetVal = toTargetVal(baseVal);

const handleBaseVal = (e) => setBaseVal(e.target.value);
const handleTargetVal = (e) => setBaseVal(fromTargetVal(e.target.value));
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right, but what if I add an input field for targetvalue and want to change it too?

Comment: @NasimB.D something like this should be enough: `setBaseVal(newTargetValue / exchangeRate)`

Comment: @NasimB.D, apologies for missing that part of your requirements! Looks like Emile has it covered. You can just use the hook to track the base value and continue to derive the target value this way.